# Is it possible to configure Azure API Management with Public IP reaching services on a VNET

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I'm studying a couple of scenarios for my infrastructure and one doubt I have is if I can configure a public facing API Management that redirects the requests to services on a VNET. The Services includes App Services and Azure Functions.

I don't want to have my services with public IPs, that's Why I want them to be on a VNET, but on the other hand I don't want to have the APIM inside a VNET unless it can still have a public static IP, which I don't think it's possible.

So I'm asking your help to create a setup in which I can securely expose a public static IP (APIM) for my clients to reach the APIs, and also protect backend services from public access (inside a VPN). this is the requirement.

thanks

Comment: You can refer to [Deploy API Management in Internal VNET with Public IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/templates/api-management-create-with-internal-vnet-publicip/) and [Connect to a virtual network using Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use API Management in external mode to access backend services deployed in the virtual network

Now, the API Management endpoints will be accessible from the public internet via an external load balancer

The API gateway can access the resources within the VNET

[image]

**Reference**: [Azure API Management with an Azure virtual network | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/virtual-network-concepts?tabs=stv2)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer, as far I understand this capability is limited to premium tier isn't it?

Comment: Which tier are you using for your API Management?

Comment: At the moment Consumer and Developer, but I'm still in the beginning. As far as I read since posting this. Only Premium allows this setup. but that is outside of the scope of this question. I was asking in case you are more experienced

Answer (score -2):

Setup Azure API service in external mode. VNet integration is supported both in Premium as well as Developer tier.